# Two different ways to take the derivative on composite functions?

Tags: calculus

Let $f(y) = xy$, and let $y = g(x)$, according to the chain rule $\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{df}{dy} \frac{dy}{dx}$ which gives us  $\frac{df}{dx} = x \frac{dg}{dx}$, but if I plug it straight in I can use the product rule to get $\frac{df}{dx}= g + x \frac{dg}{dx}$. Why have I reached this contradiction?

Answer (score 1):

To calculate $\frac{df}{dy}$, we need to use the Product Rule. The result is $x+y\frac{dx}{dy}$. When we multiply by $\frac{dy}{dx}$, we get $x\frac{dy}{dx}+y$.